# Action support rerender not showing Outputpanel

Tags: apex, visualforce, rerender, actionfunction, actionsupport

Switching between Radio Option should show and hide Outputpanel. I got this working with following code:

```
     <apex:selectRadio id="benefitradioid" required="True" value="{!selectedTargetBenefit}" style="float:left;">
          <apex:selectOption itemLabel="SECOND" itemValue="secondvalue"/>
         <apex:selectOption itemLabel="THIRD" itemValue="thirdvalue"/>

         <apex:actionSupport action="{!setSpecifiedBenefitLevel}" reRender="myPanelID"/> 
</apex:selectRadio>

<apex:outputPanel id="myPanelID" rendered="{!showBenefitLevel}">
     <apex:inputText ----********************>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

**and in Controller :**

```
public void setSpecifiedBenefitLevel(){
   System.Debug('----'+selectedTargetBenefit);
    if(selectedTargetBenefit=='secondvalue'){
        showBenefitLevel=True'
    }
}
```

My debug logs doesn't show anything.
What could be the issue or any changes I need to do ?

Answer (score 2):

Found Solution !!! Following thing Worked
**Replace the Code**

```
 <apex:outputPanel id="myPanelID" rendered="{!showBenefitLevel}">
              <apex:inputText ----********************>
       </apex:outputPanel>
```

**with this  one**

```
<apex:outputPanel id="myPanelID">
    <apex:outputPanel id="myInnerPanelID" rendered="{!showBenefitLevel}">
          <apex:inputText ----********************>
   </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: I believe the reason this works is that when an outputpanel is not rendered on the page, it literally doesn't exist on the page to be re-rendered. So you have to have an outer element that is rendered all the time and so will be addressable by the actionSupport. When that rerenders, the page re-evaluates the `rendered=` logic of everything inside it.